# How know count the number of occurrences given a char and the number of occurence

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working with SQL Server 2008 and I have the following problem.

I have a table like this:

[image]

Each column represents a year, the purpose is to know if in any column there is a repeated character a defined number of times (the character to look for and the number of occurrences are parameters).

The question is, how can I know if there is a column where the character parameter was presented n times?

For example, only to know if in some record, in any column the character '2' is repeated 3 times

An example that you perform: I search if the character '1' is repeated 6 times in the column ANIO_1

```
Declare @charToFind varchar(3) = '1'
Declare @Ocurrences int = 6, @result INT

SELECT @result = 
COUNT(COALESCE(LEN(ANIO_1) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_1,@charToFind,'')), 
LEN(ANIO_1), 0))
FROM 
#MATRIZ_HISTORICO_PAGOS
WHERE 
COALESCE(LEN(ANIO_1) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_1,@charToFind,'')), LEN(ANIO_1), 0) = @Ocurrences

SELECT CASE WHEN @result > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NO MATCH' END
```

But the purpose of my question is how to know if the number 1 is repeated 6 times in any column of the table

Thanks for your help and sorry for my English

Comment: Post one example based on any one column so that it will be easy to understand rather than guess.

Comment: I am not an SQL guy but, I guess you'll need regex to do this. For each column you can count rows where column values is like .222. If you are writing an sp you can create the regex string on the fly.

Comment: @Susang i updated my question with an example

Comment: Why this trouble & what's the purpose of your question if there isn't any meaningful data ?

Comment: @Susang the purpose is to know if the character exists in a record n times to be able to make a score based on this table: if character 2 exists 3 times in any column, a score returns, otherwise return zero. I hope I have solved your doubts

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample. Refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67d2a/1

```
DECLARE @OccuranceChars INT
DECLARE @FindSubString VARCHAR(5)
SET @FindSubString = '2'
SET @OccuranceChars = 3

SELECT ANIO_1, 
(LEN(ANIO_1) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_1, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) as Occurance_ANIO_1, 
ANIO_2, 
(LEN(ANIO_2) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_2, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) as Occurance_ANIO_2,
ANIO_3, 
(LEN(ANIO_3) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_3, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) as Occurance_ANIO_3,
ANIO_4, 
(LEN(ANIO_4) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_4, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) as Occurance_ANIO_4,
ANIO_5, 
(LEN(ANIO_5) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_5, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) as Occurance_ANIO_5,
ANIO_6, 
(LEN(ANIO_6) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_6, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) as Occurance_ANIO_6
FROM ANIO
WHERE (LEN(ANIO_1) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_1, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) = @OccuranceChars
OR (LEN(ANIO_2) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_2, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) = @OccuranceChars
OR (LEN(ANIO_3) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_3, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) = @OccuranceChars
OR (LEN(ANIO_4) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_4, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) = @OccuranceChars
OR (LEN(ANIO_5) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_5, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) = @OccuranceChars
OR (LEN(ANIO_6) - LEN(REPLACE(ANIO_6, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) = @OccuranceChars
```

Above query will check that "2" number exists **exactly** 3 times in the column "ANIO_1". For all column, you can repeat the same thing,

Else create the UDF -  user-defined function which accepts the parameter @FindSubString & Column value

Comment: @Victor Hernandez - I have modified my example with all columns, please refer the new one.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67d2a/1

Comment: its a good idea @Mittal so i can sum all ocurrences columns and check if is greater than 0 and return if the number 2 exist 3 times in any column of all rows, right?

Comment: My example gives you the number of  Occurrence for given string per column. As per your requirement you can use that Occurrence  column